# Perfect-scrollbar with relative height

Tags: jquery, html, perfect-scrollbar

I'm using perfect-scrollbar to customise scrollbar in my application . Now i have a situation where I wish to have a height of the scrollable section defined in terms of percentage . I tried to set the height to percentage but its not working .

Here is the sample

```
<style>
  .contentHolderSearch{ 
    position:relative; 
    margin:0px auto; 
    padding:0px; height:20%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
</style>
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  "use strict";
    $('#movieScroll').perfectScrollbar();
  });
</script>
<div id="peopleScroll" class="contentHolderSearch">
  ----------some content----------------
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1):

Perfect scrollbar supports dynamic height as I can see it in [example](http://jsfiddle.net/N53mJ/). Maybe you should change `$('#movieScroll').perfectScrollbar();` to `$('#peopleScroll').perfectScrollbar();` ?